# Looking for a specific Harry Potter fanfiction

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

What I can remember:

- Harry lives with the Dursleys, he and Dudley go to the park. Harry plays with a girl while her mother watches.
- The girl's mother eventually talks to Petunia on the park bench about taking guardianship of Harry. (I think the mother threatens Petunia.) Petunia agrees.
- Once Harry moves in, he and the girl sleep in the same bed and play naked. (Not sexually, they are very young and don't care for clothes)
- As they get a bit older, they are very smart and curious. They get homeschooled.  They're taught all the normal subjects but in depth.
- At some point they find out Harry is a wizard and they learn about magic too.
- Somehow they figure a way for electronics to work around magic. He uses diamond to encase the wires and circuits and it negates the effect of magic. He also finds out a way to make diamonds himself and sells some to the goblins at Gringotts.
- The mother finds that runes in the magical world are essentially the same as circuits for electricity in the muggle world.
- I think they move into a manor and eventually have their muggle and magical friends over. I think they go bowling and have a Halloween party.

That's where my remembrance ends.

I hope someone can tell me the name or author of this fic.  I'm almost positive I read it on FanFiction.net or AO3. Thanks in advance for any answers, wrong or right.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! These might help you to improve your question; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and [How to ask a good (Fanfic) Story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11922/how-to-ask-a-good-fanfic-story-id-question)